# Data conversion in LABVIEW

Tags: type-conversion, labview

I am trying to convert an analog value to a digital value (8 bit A/D converter, input range 0-5V ).

I have used the formula (input*255/5) to convert to digital, then i have used digital to binary vi to convert this digital value to 8 bits.

The problem here is the data type mismatch between my output from the formula, which is a double data type and the input of the vi which is a digital data type, so how to solve this problem ? Thank you in advance

Comment: why not multiple by 51?  Also, what do you mean by the input of the avi?

Comment: I'm going to assume you meant digital to binary.vi and 'input of the vi'.  Can you confirm I am correct?

Comment: @seanJ yes  your right

Comment: can you edit your question to read .vi instead of avi?

Comment: @seanJ Done editing

Comment: thanks, I tried to edit but the moderators rejected my edit as they said that wasn't what you meant even though you said it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The digital data you mention is On/OFF.  The example below illustrates the type of data that is entered and output from *digital to binary.vi*

[image]

On the left hand side is three samples of digital data in continuous signal format from three separate sources, (signal 0, signal 1, signal 2).

The first sample gives binary 2 (010).  As you can see this would be not be of any use for a single signal.

If you still want to do the above, you could use *DWDT Boolean Array to Digital* as illustrated below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help , but please can you explain more how did you insert these data ( 2,7,4) to the digital to binary.vi , since there is a data type mismatch ( the source is a number and the input of digital to binary.vi is a digital data ) . Thank you

Comment: @ahmed hope that helps, if it answers the question can you accept?  Otherwise let me know what is missing and I will try and help.

Comment: Thank you very much !! It works ! Everything is fine now :)